# How do I set data values to multiple div tags in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

I want to display multiple circular progress bars, but I can't get more than one to display on the same page.

You can see in the codepen example, my attempt to add multiple div tags to display multiple progress bars, but only one appears.

I'm guessing I may need to set different values to the different div tags? Any help is appreciated.

Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/ZYbzyX

HTML:

```
<div id="progress" data-dimension="150" data-color="#eee" data-text="HTML / HTML5" data-fontsize="14" data-percent="95" data-fgcolor="#d35225" data-bgcolor="#eee" data-width="15" data-bordersize="5" data-animationstep="2"></div>
```

```
<div id="progress" data-dimension="150" data-color="#eee" data-text="HTML / HTML5" data-fontsize="14" data-percent="85" data-fgcolor="#d35225" data-bgcolor="#eee" data-width="15" data-bordersize="5" data-animationstep="2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
/* PROGRESS CIRCLE COMPONENT */
.circliful {
    margin:auto;
    position: relative; 
}

.circle-text, .circle-info, .circle-text-half, .circle-info-half {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.circle-info, .circle-info-half {
    color: #999;
}

.circliful .fa {
    margin: -10px 3px 0 3px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 4px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#progress').circliful();
});


//Note -- I removed the respondCanvas function from the circiful library
/* PROGRESS CIRCLE COMPONENT */
(function ($) {

    $.fn.circliful = function (options, callback) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            startdegree: 0,
            fgcolor: "#556b2f",
            bgcolor: "#eee",
            fill: false,
            width: 15,
            dimension: 200,
            fontsize: 15,
            percent: 50,
            animationstep: 1.0,
            iconsize: '20px',
            iconcolor: '#999',
            border: 'default',
            complete: null,
            bordersize: 10
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {

            var customSettings = ["fgcolor", "bgcolor", "fill", "width", "dimension", "fontsize", "animationstep", "endPercent", "icon", "iconcolor", "iconsize", "border", "startdegree", "bordersize"];

            var customSettingsObj = {};
            var icon = '';
            var endPercent = 0;
            var obj = $(this);
            var fill = false;
            var text, info;

            obj.addClass('circliful');

            checkDataAttributes(obj);

            if (obj.data('text') != undefined) {
                text = obj.data('text');

                if (obj.data('icon') != undefined) {
                    icon = $('<i></i>')
                        .addClass('fa ' + $(this).data('icon'))
                        .css({
                            'color': customSettingsObj.iconcolor,
                            'font-size': customSettingsObj.iconsize
                        });
                }

                if (obj.data('type') != undefined) {
                    type = $(this).data('type');

                    if (type == 'half') {
                        addCircleText(obj, 'circle-text-half', (customSettingsObj.dimension / 1.45));
                    } else {
                        addCircleText(obj, 'circle-text', customSettingsObj.dimension);
                    }
                } else {
                    addCircleText(obj, 'circle-text', customSettingsObj.dimension);
                }
            }

            if ($(this).data("total") != undefined && $(this).data("part") != undefined) {
                var total = $(this).data("total") / 100;

                percent = (($(this).data("part") / total) / 100).toFixed(3);
                endPercent = ($(this).data("part") / total).toFixed(3)
            } else {
                if ($(this).data("percent") != undefined) {
                    percent = $(this).data("percent") / 100;
                    endPercent = $(this).data("percent")
                } else {
                    percent = settings.percent / 100
                }
            }

            if ($(this).data('info') != undefined) {
                info = $(this).data('info');

                if ($(this).data('type') != undefined) {
                    type = $(this).data('type');

                    if (type == 'half') {
                        addInfoText(obj, 0.9);
                    } else {
                        addInfoText(obj, 1.25);
                    }
                } else {
                    addInfoText(obj, 1.25);
                }
            }

            $(this).width(customSettingsObj.dimension + 'px');

            var canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>').attr({
                width: customSettingsObj.dimension,
                height: customSettingsObj.dimension
            }).appendTo($(this)).get(0);

            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var container = $(canvas).parent();
            var x = canvas.width / 2;
            var y = canvas.height / 2;
            var degrees = customSettingsObj.percent * 360.0;
            var radians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
            var radius = canvas.width / 2.5;
            var startAngle = 2.3 * Math.PI;
            var endAngle = 0;
            var counterClockwise = false;
            var curPerc = customSettingsObj.animationstep === 0.0 ? endPercent : 0.0;
            var curStep = Math.max(customSettingsObj.animationstep, 0.0);
            var circ = Math.PI * 2;
            var quart = Math.PI / 2;
            var type = '';
            var fireCallback = true;
            var additionalAngelPI = (customSettingsObj.startdegree / 180) * Math.PI;

            if ($(this).data('type') != undefined) {
                type = $(this).data('type');

                if (type == 'half') {
                    startAngle = 2.0 * Math.PI;
                    endAngle = 3.13;
                    circ = Math.PI;
                    quart = Math.PI / 0.996;
                }
            }

            /**
             * adds text to circle
             *
             * @param obj
             * @param cssClass
             * @param lineHeight
             */
            function addCircleText(obj, cssClass, lineHeight) {
                $("<span></span>")
                    .appendTo(obj)
                    .addClass(cssClass)
                    .text(text)
                    .prepend(icon)
                    .css({
                        'line-height': lineHeight + 'px',
                        'font-size': customSettingsObj.fontsize + 'px'
                    });
            }

            /**
             * adds info text to circle
             *
             * @param obj
             * @param factor
             */
            function addInfoText(obj, factor) {
                $('<span></span>')
                    .appendTo(obj)
                    .addClass('circle-info-half')
                    .css(
                        'line-height', (customSettingsObj.dimension * factor) + 'px'
                    )
                    .text(info);
            }

            /**
             * checks which data attributes are defined
             * @param obj
             */
            function checkDataAttributes(obj) {
                $.each(customSettings, function (index, attribute) {
                    if (obj.data(attribute) != undefined) {
                        customSettingsObj[attribute] = obj.data(attribute);
                    } else {
                        customSettingsObj[attribute] = $(settings).attr(attribute);
                    }

                    if (attribute == 'fill' && obj.data('fill') != undefined) {
                        fill = true;
                    }
                });
            }

            /**
             * animate foreground circle
             * @param current
             */
            function animate(current) {

                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(x, y, radius, endAngle, startAngle, false);

                context.lineWidth = customSettingsObj.bordersize + 1;

                context.strokeStyle = customSettingsObj.bgcolor;
                context.stroke();

                if (fill) {
                    context.fillStyle = customSettingsObj.fill;
                    context.fill();
                }

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(x, y, radius, -(quart) + additionalAngelPI, ((circ) * current) - quart + additionalAngelPI, false);

                if (customSettingsObj.border == 'outline') {
                    context.lineWidth = customSettingsObj.width + 13;
                } else if (customSettingsObj.border == 'inline') {
                    context.lineWidth = customSettingsObj.width - 13;
                }

                context.strokeStyle = customSettingsObj.fgcolor;
                context.stroke();

                if (curPerc < endPercent) {
                    curPerc += curStep;
                    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                        animate(Math.min(curPerc, endPercent) / 100);
                    }, obj);
                }

                if (curPerc == endPercent && fireCallback && typeof(options) != "undefined") {
                    if ($.isFunction(options.complete)) {
                        options.complete();

                        fireCallback = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            animate(curPerc / 100);

        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Can't have two of an ID on a page. Check it out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwdPQm (.progress is a bootstrap class)

Comment: @Chad I see - you changed from id to class. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 2):

Each `div` needs its own ID.  In fact, every ID needs to be unique for a page to function correctly.  The `#progress` selector will only pick up one element at most.

In this case, I'd use a class instead of an ID anyway:

```
<div class="progress" data-dimension="150" data-color="#eee" data-text="HTML / HTML5" data-fontsize="14" data-percent="95" data-fgcolor="#d35225" data-bgcolor="#eee" data-width="15" data-bordersize="5" data-animationstep="2"></div>
<br/>

<div class="progress" data-dimension="150" data-color="#eee" data-text="HTML / HTML5" data-fontsize="14" data-percent="85" data-fgcolor="#d35225" data-bgcolor="#eee" data-width="15" data-bordersize="5" data-animationstep="2"></div>
<br/>
```

And initialize:

```
$(function() {
    $('.progress').circliful();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than one ID's to a page.

But you *can* have multiple classes.

**JS:**

Changed 
`$('#progress')` to `$('.progress')`

**HTML:**

Changed `id="progress"` to `class="progress"`